# Using environment variables with su -c

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, su

I try to run `nvm` as a different user from a bash script. It is installed already and the `NVM_DIR` environment variable is set in `/home/user/.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

Using plain `su` works:

```
root@ubuntu:~# su user
user@:/root$ echo $NVM_DIR
/home/user/.nvm
```

Trying the same thing with `su -c` does not work though:

```
root@ubuntu:~# su user -c 'echo $NVM_DIR'

root@ubuntu:~#
```

How can I use environment variables with `su -c`?

Comment: Yes, it is set (only) in `user`'s bashrc

Comment: @steeldriver I have extended my question. Using single quotes does not work either.

Comment: Check this response from........: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123317/passing-arguments-to-su-provided-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're observing is because `su -c 'command'` does not execute `command` in an interactive shell.

Since `su` doesn't appear to provide an option to do so, probably the cleanest way to do what you want is to move the NVM environment variables into a separate file, called `nvm_envs` say, and source that explicitly e.g.

```
su user -c '. ~/nvm_envs && echo $NVM_DIR'
```

If you want interactive bash shells to have the same environment, source the same file from your `.bashrc` file e.g.

```
if [ -r "$HOME/nvm_envs" ]; then
  . "$HOME/nvm_envs"
fi
```

(This is exactly how the default `.profile` file conditionally sources the user's `env_vars` file: you could use that file instead if you prefer.)

Comment: What about `su - user -c 'echo $NVM_DIR'`? With the additional `-`?

Comment: @PerlDuck that will force it to use a login shell, which - if the user's login shell is `bash`, at least with the default Ubuntu `~/.profile`, will read their `~/.bashrc`: however, the default `~/.bashrc` basically just exits if the shell is non-interactive. It would work if the environment variables were defined *before* the interactivity test - but that feels kind of wrong somehow.

Comment: @PerlDuck I also tried that, did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @thesys Okay. Was just an idea. But steeldrivers explanation and suggestion seems reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
sudo -i -u user sh -c 'echo $NVM_DIR'
```

Comment: You used double quotes, so `NVM_DIR` is expanded by your current shell, not `sh`.